# Repairing a grass verge

Tags: grass

It has been a wet winter, and the grass verges have been driven over and got mangled.

Looking a bit like this :
[image: chewed up grass verge]

I don't really want to replace it with hard standing, so it will probably be a dig over and reseed. Although I am thinking a "football pitch" seed mix.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest any better approaches, that would leave this green,  but a little more durable (I know making it indestructible is impossible)

Answer (score 6):

You can try a sports pitch mix, but really, turf of any description is not able to withstand vehicles driving over it when it's wet, and you'll still end up with the same mess you've got now, so I'm not sure the extra cost of using something harder wearing is worth it. It will withstand foot traffic a little better, but not enough to make it a worthwhile investment, and any ordinary, dry turf will tolerate the occasional incursion by vehicle wheels, but if it's very wet, having sports grade turf will make no difference I'm afraid. This is equally true of any other type of planting.

I live opposite a sports field - currently, it's a mess from lots of rugby played in very wet conditions. What you're maybe not aware of is just how much work it takes by the groundsmen to repair and keep the turf in good condition, it's a full time job, and the same would be true of your roadside verge.

Comment: is right. It's not the turf that's been destroyed, it's the soil that has been crushed and shifted tearing plants tops and roots alike. You need something to harden the soil, like CA-6  (crushed aggregate size 6) gravel turned into the soil by at least 6 inches. This will give the soil support when it gets wet. You may need to repeat this process for 2 or 3 years until it hardens up.

Answer (score 3):

Is the grass verge yours? It's difficult if it's a public verge. My sympathies in trying to prevent this from becoming a passing space. It may benefit in trying to build up the height of the verge which would emphasise that it's a verge and not driving space. Would your local parish council be of any help in sorting this out if nothing else but advice on what you are allowed to do next to a public highway? If it's yours would you be allowed to put bollards there? Large enough to be seen by drivers, but you would need to be able to mow around them.

Comment: Oh, I understand it's getting driven/parked on when necessary, and I'm fairly sanguine about that. I was just hoping there was a solution that didn't result in either mashed up mud piles or having to pave over.

Answer (score 3):

Something in place like 'Hoggin' It's a semi hard mix of stone, gravel and earths.  It's tamped into place. Often seen as driveways and paths in stately homes.  It's natural and can be naturalised by grasses and other plants, but is hardish wearing and relatively cheap, especially if you need to repeat patch.  It might be an option.  If it's on a public highway you may not be allowed to put kerb stones and build up the verge that way.

Answer (score 1):

Is installing some type of [grass grid](https://www.google.com/search?q=grass%20grid&espv=2&biw=1070&bih=593&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkivjn6sPKAhUS82MKHU9ABPkQsAQITg) possible?